# Vim YouCompleteMe c++17 : warning on decomposition declaration

Tags: vim, c++17, youcompleteme

I would like to set YouCompleteMe correctly so that I do not get the following warning on a c++ file:

```cpp
...

auto [k,v] = mapIt; // some map iterator

...
```

```
decomposition declarations are a C++17 extension
```

I added

```
   flags.append( '-std=c++17' )
```

in

```
~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/.ycm_extra_conf.py
```

and added the following to

```
~/.vimrc
```

```
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
```

Comment: I'm not sure StackOverflow is the best channel to get help for YouCompleteMe. I suggest that you give a look [here](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#help-advice-support).

Comment: I’ve rolled-back your edits. The correct way to answer a question on Stack Exchange is to post an answer

Answer (score 4):

I decided to remove the previous installation and do everything from the command line (assuming previous Vundle installation as recommended in YouCompleteMe docs).

```sh
# typical installation directory for vundle and pathogen
cd ~/.vim/bundle

# clone the repository for YouCompleteMe
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
cd YouCompleteMe

# and all submodules
git submodule update --init --recursive

# install
python3 install.py --clang-completer
```

Next I created a simple ycm_extra_conf.py (without the .dot) containing:

```py
def FlagsForFile ( filename, **kwargs ):
    return {
        'flags': ['-x', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror', '-std=c++2a']
    }
```

I added the c++2a flag, but c++17 should also work.

Then point to this file in your ~/.vimrc file.

```
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '$HOME/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/ycm_extra_conf.py'
```

Note: you may have to add to your ~/.vimrc

```
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
```

in your vimrc file.

And run (from vim)

```
:PluginInstall
```

I didn't do these steps as I had installed YouCompleteMe previously.

This seems to have fixed the problem for me.  Hope this can be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

just change the flag `'-std=c++11'` to `'-std=c++17'` in the .ycm_extra_conf.py .

that works for me perfectly.

Comment: Where is .ycm_extra_conf.py?